# Jquery 1.10 combination of live() and clone() - weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

i want to clone a element and insert on another position in the DOM. (So actually i just want to 'move' it).

On document ready some events get binded in a Plugin (which i don't want to edit) to a child element of the element i want to clone.

When i clone the element like this:

```
$('.FSGD-logo-slider-element-info').each(function(){
    $number = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $element = $(this).clone(true, true);

    $('.FSGD-logo-slider-element[data-index="'+$number+'"]').after($element);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The element is cloned, but they don't react on any Events.

When i do it like this (Have a look on the third line with the live-method):

```
$('.FSGD-logo-slider-element-info').each(function(){
    $number = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $element = $(this).live().clone(true, true);

    $('.FSGD-logo-slider-element[data-index="'+$number+'"]').after($element);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

It is working. But the live method is removed since jquery 1.9, because of that i also get an error output.

I can't explain why that code is working and i don't have any idea to get it working without the live method.

I hope someone is able to help. That would be awesome.

Comment: I think it must be observational error, triple-check your results.

Comment: `live()` does not exist in jQuery 1.10.

Comment: Even if live() was supported, `$(this).live()` makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, and that's why i have no idea why it was working. Nevertheless, now it's working with crowders hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to clone a element and insert on another position in the DOM. (So actually i just want to 'move' it).

Then just move it:

```
$('.FSGD-logo-slider-element-info').each(function(){
    var $number = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $('.FSGD-logo-slider-element[data-index="'+$number+'"]').after(this);
});
```

Example:

```js
// Hook an event on a child of the info elements
$(".FSGD-logo-slider-element-info input").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).parent().attr("data-trigger"));
});

// Move the elements
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.FSGD-logo-slider-element-info').each(function(){
    var $number = $(this).attr('data-trigger');

    $('.FSGD-logo-slider-element[data-index="'+$number+'"]').after(this);
  });
  
  $("p").remove();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element-info" data-trigger="1">
  Info One <input type="button" value="Click me">
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element-info" data-trigger="2">
  Info Two <input type="button" value="Click me">
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element-info" data-trigger="3">
  Info Three <input type="button" value="Click me">
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element-info" data-trigger="4">
   Info Four <input type="button" value="Click me">
</div>

<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element" data-index="1">
  Element One
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element" data-index="2">
  Element Two
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element" data-index="3">
  Element Three
</div>
<div class="FSGD-logo-slider-element" data-index="4">
  Element Four
</div>

<p>Elements will move after a second</p>
```

---

Side note: I added `var` in front of `$number = ...` above. Without it, your code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (unless of course it was declared in a parent scope, but this is clearly used as a local, so that wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know, that after() is just moving an element!

Comment: @Hayo: No problem. Yes, it's actually a DOM feature: If you append or insert a node that' into a new location, it's *moved*.